# how to remove a given key from a series of maps in a vector in clojure?

Tags: clojure, lisp, clojurescript

In clojure, given a data structure `[{:a "foo" :b "bar"} {:a "biz" :b "baz"}]` how would I get `[{:b "bar"}{:b "baz"}]` the most succinctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`dissoc`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dissoc) is a function for dissociating a key from an associative structure like a map. Here's how you'd do it with one map:

```
(dissoc my-map :a)
```

If you have a sequence of maps, you can `map` a function over them to `dissoc` the key(s) from each map:

```
(map #(dissoc % :a) the-maps)
```

This phrasing passes an [anonymous function](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/functions#_anonymous_functions) to `map`, but depending on usage you may want to extract a named function:

```
(defn fix-the-map [m]
  (dissoc m :a))

(map fix-the-map the-maps)
```

Comment: You may also wish to use `mapv` instead of `map`, since it always gives you the result in a Clojure vector instead of a lazy seq.

Comment: I think some people are way too eager to get vector results. I don't like to give up laziness without a good reason.

Comment: As a matter of style, while map is great with named functions, instead of `(map #(...) xs)` I personally prefer to write a list comprehension. So, `(for [m the-maps] (dissoc m :a))`.

Answer (score 2):

@Taylor's above answer to `dissoc` `:a` from each map is fine if you want all maps without `:a`.

In case if you want a list of maps with just `:b` key, you can do

```
<!-- language-all: lang-clj -->

;; Assuming my-map is the object map
;; map returns a lazy sequence

(map #(hash-map :b (:b %)) my-map)

;; or
(map #(select-keys % [:b]) mp)
```